# How to redirect to a page in jquery after the event

Tags: jquery, redirect

```
$('.enter_web_button').click(function(){  
  $('.loading_logo').animate({
     left:'40%'  
  },1000);

 $('.nav_business').animate({
 left:'100%' 
 },1000,function(){ 
 $(this).hide(1000);

    // go to test.php           
 });

});
```

After finishing the event i want to redirect the page to test.php.how to do it..?
thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) for that

```
window.location.href = 'text.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `window.location.replace` as mentioned below:

```
window.location.replace('text.php')
```

**OR**

You may use `window.location.href` as mentioned below:

```
window.location.href = 'text.php'
```

Comment: `window.location.href` is not a method.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using location.assign as bellow:

```
location.assign('your_page.php');
```

For more information, please check Mozilla documentation: [Mozilla MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)